# How to add a link/joint in runtime

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello!

Id like to know if its possible to edit a robot in runtime by adding new Links/Joints to it while still having the simulation running and affecting the whole model (unlike the method editor). Ive stumbled upon this [UpdateParameters](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/4.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Base.html#a0878d76d331a70e5b0d7689bc883b648) method, but Im not quite sure this will do what I want, although updating an SRDF seems promising.

Im currently using Gazebo 4 on Ubuntu Precise.

If this is possible, does anyone know how to accomplish it ?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7801/how-to-add-a-link/joint-in-runtime/) by [Trmotta](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/628/trmotta/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you can create new models similarly to [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world&cat=write_plugin) tutorial, I am not sure if you can add a new links to an existing model, but, you can connect links of different models.

The code should be something like this:

```
physics::JointPtr joint;

joint = this->world->GetPhysicsEngine()->CreateJoint("revolute", model1);

joint->Load(model1_link, model2_link, math::Pose());

joint->Attach(model1_link, model2_link);

joint->SetAxis(0, axis_ex);

joint->SetHighStop(0, high_stop_ex);
...
joint->SetParam("cfm", 0, cfm_ex);
...
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Trmotta](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/628/trmotta/) on 2015-01-13**:
Thanks! That solved it!

**Comment by [awesomebytes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/950/awesomebytes/) on 2016-04-19**:
(Edited) I made a plugin to attach any two links in gazebo: https://github.com/pal-robotics/gazebo_ros_link_attacher